# What happened to President Walker's immunity?

Tags: house-of-cards

When Claire was talking to the woman during the campaign, we heard that the woman said, "like when he pardoned Walker and the other guy, the rich one"

I understand why he pardoned Tusk, but why would Walker be subjected to charges if he was the President of the United States, which in my knowledge, cannot be persecuted.

Is it because he 'was' the POTUS when he resigned, so he could be charged again with cases he did during his presidency; or because the alleged corruption was done before he became the POTUS, which is during his campaigning.

Comment: I could get *really* political on this one, but won't ... Even POTUS is subject to laws. When a sitting president is indicted, it's actually called impeachment. Impeachment doesn't mean someone's guilty, but rather POTUS is accused of the crime and will be brought to trial (one way or another). Walker was pardoned so he could not be prosecuted. I'm not remember why exactly he was pardoned, so I'm leaving this as a comment (I need to go back and watch the second season again).

Comment: I think he was pardoned because Tusk lyingly admitted that Walker knows that the money that they used for campaigning is from a foreign source, which is (illegal?)

Comment: And Walker wasn't impeached, he resigned before impeachment trials right? I'm not sure about this.

Comment: That's a very good question. I think the New Hampshire lady could only mean that Frank somehow pardoned Walker from impeachment. Walker was indeed never impeached, but he also wasn't pardoned (by Frank or anyone else). He simply resigned before the impeachment. **We** know that Frank had a role in it, but how would she? Was it a mistake of the writers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember Garrett Walker was facing the impeachment and a special investigation for his participation in the Feng-Tusk money laundering's scheme through international donations.

Walker resigned before the impeachment but the investigation was ongoing; we can assume also that the investigation ended because Frank's orders. After all, the Justice Department didn't take part with FULL authority, because the *"special"* part. And if the investigation finished finding Walker guilty, I bet Underwood gave him the pardon, just like Raymond Tusk.